# Passing the id of another element into the onclick event of a button?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make it so that when I click on a button above a clock element that I have, it changes it from am to pm. I have many clock elements, each associated with their own am/pm buttons. Here is what I tried (piechart0 is the clock and clock.js is where I handle my js for it):

```
<button class="button2" onclick="Clock.toAm("piechart0")">AM</button>
<button class="button2" onclick="Clock.toPm("piechart0")">PM</button>
<canvas id="piechart0" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

With this as my javascript:

```
Clock.toAm = function(id) {
    var clock = document.getElementById(id);
    clock.am = true;
    for (var j = 0; j < 48; j++) {
        clock.segments[j] = clock.amSegments[j];
        clock.updateDraw(j);
    }
}

Clock.toPm = function(id) {
    var clock = document.getElementById(id);
    clock.pm = true;
    for (var j = 0; j < 48; j++) {
        clock.segments[j] = clock.pmSegments[j];
        clock.updateDraw(j);
    }
}
```

But I get a "attribute piechart0 is not allowed here" notification. What am I doing wrong here/how can I pass in another id to the argument of a button's onclick argument?

EDIT: I see that I may be having quotation conflicts. Now, with using '  ' quotations I get the reference to piechart0, but whereas the actual piechart0 variables are all defined, when I complete:

```
var clock = document.getElementById(id);
```

All of this element's variables are undefined. I am not sure why this is the case since I am using the same id?

Comment: you have this tagged as jquery. Any reason you're not using `$('.class2').click()`?

Comment: Adding custom property on HTML element (HTMLCanvasElement) is not considered good practice, where do you define them ?

Comment: Without quotes what doesn't work? Is it the same error?

Comment: Change either outer or inner quotes `"` to single quotes `'`, like this `onclick="Clock.toPm('piechart0')">`

Answer (score 1):

Change one of the double quotes to be single in the onclick prop

```
<button class="button2" onclick='Clock.toAm("piechart0")'>AM</button>
<button class="button2" onclick='Clock.toPm("piechart0")'>PM</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple suggestions:

For debugging this I would insert a `console.log(id)` and see what's actually getting through. Assuming you replace the quote mismatch with `onclick="Clock.toPm('piechart0')"` the value should get through just fine.

Since you have this tagged as `jQuery`, I would use `.click()` i.e. something like:

HTML

```
<button id="btnPm">PM</button>
```

Javascript:

```
$('button#btnPm').click(function() { Clock.toPm('piechart0'); });
```

As for `clock.am`, I'm not sure if modifying a DOM object like this can be made to work. For sure, though, it would be discouraged. I would suggest using `.prop()`, i.e. `$(clock).prop('am', true)`

Comment: This was correct in getting the Id through. Now, however, when I do:

    var clock = document.getElementById(id);

All of this element's variables are undefined. I am not sure why this is the case since I am using the same id, and it correctly identifies that element as a canvas#piechart0?

Comment: do you mean to say `var clock` is undefined? or are you getting a message like `toPm is not a member of Clock`? Being specific will help you get a quicker answer

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. var clock IS defined as "canvas#piechart0", but all of its variables are undefined. Upon instantiation of a piechart (for example) every clock's "am" variable = true. My clock with the id of piechart0 has "am = true;". But with var clock, even though it is defined as "canvas#piechart0" all of those variables are undefined, "am = undefined;"

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect this. Hope it works for you.